# Is noetherian ring finite over subring of invariants of a finite group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $G$ be finite group, $R$ is a commutative ring and $G$ acts on $R$ by ring automorphisms. It is well known and easy to show that extension $R^G \subset R$ is integral. It also not hard to find examples when such extension is not finite. But in all examples I know $R$ is not noetherian.

> Is $R$ finite over $R^G$ for a noetherian ring $R$?

Comment: Example 5.5 from *Fixed Rings of Finite Automorphism Groups of Associative Rings*.